# JQuery include on page refresh

Tags: jquery, include

This is the code i have.

```
if(!window.jQuery) {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = LIB_URL+"js_files/jquery.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = LIB_URL+"js_files/myjs.js"; //needs jquery to be loaded
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

The problem is that the first time i load the page from the url bar (load or reload the page), jquery is included and everything is ok. When i hit f5 to refresh the page it gives the fallowing error:

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(function(){

But when i look into the  of the page document jquery it is included. How can i make sure that this will work not only if i reload the page but also on refresh. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should look into `require.js` to manage loading scripts for you.  Chances are you are loading both on refresh, but the second one is loading faster from cache than the jQuery script.

Comment: @Lachezar Dynamic script loading will not guarantee you to load the scripts you have called in order.It is entirely based on time taken to load the script. Script which comes first, gets loaded first. When I have stuck up with the same issue, i tried require.js. That worked well. Just add require.js in your site to manage loading the scripts in order. Hope that will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

jq.onload = procede;  //DON'T TYPE PARENTHESIS!

//i.e. 'procede()' runs INSTANTLY (NOT WHEN LOADED)
//     'procede' gives it a function to run when it's ready (what you want!)

...

function procede () {
//jQuery commands are loaded (do your magic)


}
```

Comment: did that answer the question? another problem i've had before is: when i refresh the page while looking at the console, my script thought the current window was the html console page, rather than the actual site (i needed to press f12 **AFTER** the page was done loading)